# Screen flickering slightly on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I am using a 2021 14" MacBook with M1 Pro. Starting a few days back, the screen is very slightly flickering. The color is same and doesn't switch from black/white, it only slightly fluctuates in brightness. It also slightly lags - the refresh rate is not as smooth as it used to seem.

I have restarted and even updated to Ventura 13.2. Does anyone know any fix for this? I have taken an ungodly amount of care of my Mac, and would never have let anything come into contact with force onto the screen.

Comment: Can you expand on “flickering” and “lagging”?  For instance, does it go black/white and back to the image?  As for “lagging,” how it it doing this and in relation to what?  What makes the image lag?

Comment: Can you capture this from a phone so we can see it? Also, if you capture it as a 'screenshot' [cmd/shift/5 for options] does it look the same? [You may need to play back on another device to be able to tell.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I took a screen recording, but it was not visible on a second device. I also reset my SMC / NVRAM

Comment: It sounds like it's possibly hardware. I'd take it to Apple to have a look at.

Comment: Yeah, I took it to them. They are replacing the display, as its a defect with the backlight on the display. Surprisingly they didn't try to cheat me out of the warranty.